# Ubuntu/Lubuntu 16.04 External Microphone (Headphone) Detected but not Working

Tags: 16.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

Hello and thanks for visiting my question thread.

My laptop is Asus X45A. I fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04 because I cant upgrade it from previous LTS. Then I installed another desktop environment which is Lubuntu because it is lot lighter.

My laptop **only has one jack slot of sound**, for sound in, sound out or both. So **I use my Samsung headphone** to listen to the sound and to record my voice. This can be done very good in my Windows 10 with Realtek (my laptop is dualboot)

When I try it in Ubuntu, I can listen for the sound very good, but unfortunately, **the microphone of the headphone is not working**. The **microphone is detected** in pavucontrol, and **the range bar is moving BUT randomly and not depend on my voice**.

Another thing I want to tell you is, **when I press** volume up, down or the answer **button in my headphone**, **the bar moving to the corner right**, like when the input sound is very loud.

I notice the different between input and output devices tab in pavucontrol. In output devices tab has headphones listed but with "(plugged in)", so it say "**Headphones (plugged in)**" but in output devices there is  just "**Microphone** without plugged in text or else.

I have try few things and didn't work, and unfortunately I dont remember all the steps that I try. Like changing the alsa-base.conf and alsamixer for example, and any else. So I'll post a result of few commands that maybe helpful to solve my problem.

Sorry for my english if it's hard to read, I'm still learning hehe. If there any else command that I have to run, please post here.
Thanks for your support :)

---

Here is the link of the screenshot of my pavucontrol "Input Devices" tab:
(I cant thumbnail the uploaded image yet)
[as you can see, the microphone is detected and the bar is moving like it has input sound but it moves randomly not depending on my voice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l61J.jpg)

My alsamixer:
[I just playing with alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YyiS.png)

When I run "**cat /proc/asound/cards**" the result is:

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e10000 irq 30
```

The result of "**sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf**"

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2


options snd-pcsp index=-2

alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel

alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel

options snd-hda-intel model=asus-x45a

options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=1

options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1 enable=yes
```

Comment: I have basically identical problem but in my case the laptop is Acer TMP648-MG-554H. If you even sumbled upon anything that is at least related to these issues, I would love to hear it. It drives me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Alsamixer is nice, yoU can see devices that are off by accident. However I don't thinkits usage is entirely clear.

I also use pavucontrol for same purpose. For me, it offers better view of devices. I often find headset volume is set at 00, have to increase. In the recording panel, it has excellent self awareness.

This is worth testing, I still use daily to switch sound input and output devices while recording screencasts.

Comment: This is not even an attempt to an answer, just a plain comment totally unrelated to solving this problem.